# Is there a comma between that and a temporal prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositions, commas, syntactic-analysis

I've been struggling with the following sentence: "The Complaint also alleges that between May 2013 and February 2017, ABC transferred approximately $5,823,243.07 in rental payments to Atlantic Bank."

Should there be a comma at "that, between..."? Or should I just rewrite to say "The Complaint also alleges that ABC transferred approximately $5,823,243.07 in rental payments to Atlantic Bank between May 2013 and February 2017."

Thanks!

Comment: You have two options: put the comma after "that" _or_ remove the comma after "February 2017". If you have both commas in place the phrase "between May 2013 and February 2017" becomes _parenthetical_. That is it could be removed and the rest of the sentence would still work. If you leave them both out you are indicating that the sentence is a single entity and that all the parts are essential to the understanding of it. What would be wrong would be to leave either one in place without the other. You could also, as you say, put the phrase with the dates in at back of the sentence.

Comment: You can set off the temporal adjunct with punctuation if you wish, but is optional.